# # turning to exe when running terminal command

Tags: command-line, external-command

First of, I am sure there are plugins that will do what I am trying to achieve but I am using this as an exercise to learn vim as I am still quite new so I am not really interested in plugin suggestions.

I am trying to build a command that will pope the current line of my buffer through Pandoc and replace the line with the output.  This would allow me to, for example, have the line:

```
# Title
```

turn into

```
<h1>Title</h1>
```

in an html document.  In time I would like it to output different text based on the buffer's file type but for now I am focusing on html.  This is what I have so far:

```
exe "read !echo " . getline('.') " | pandoc -t html"
```

I am aware that at the moment this won't replace the current line but that is intentional whilst I'm debugging

With my cursor on the line `#test`, I got the following added to the line below it:

```
<p>exetest</p>
```

It appears to me that the `#` is being converted to `exe` before it is piped into pandoc.  Could you please tell me why this is and how to fix it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with your command is that you're constructing a piece of Vimscript with constructs a piece of shell script. Both require some careful handling to take care of "special" characters such as `#`. For example:

```
:exe "read !echo " . shellescape(escape(getline('.'), '#%')) " | pandoc -t html"
```

This still won't cover all the cases, though, and I wouldn't recommend using it. If you want to add a new line with the output below the current one, then a better way is probably:

```
:call append('.', systemlist('pandoc -t html', getline('.')))
```

This avoids having to escape Vimscript because you're not building the command with `exe`, and the second argument to `systemlist()` is passed as the command's stdin, so you avoid shell escaping with that as well!

---

You can also use a motion with `!`; the `.` motion is the current line so this:

```
:.!pandoc -t html
```

will replace the current line with the output of pandoc.